# Pass/Return a value in reject() when an error occurs

Tags: node.js, es6-promise

How can I return a value using reject() when using promises?

I am trying to access an AWS S3 bucket from my node.js code. Here's my [code](https://jsfiddle.net/bunnyrabbit/tb0rmzjv/)

If the operation is successful, I resolve the promise with the s3Info object. If there is an error, I want to reject the promise, again returning the s3Info object, but with the error message. I am unable to get the s3Info{} with the error message when an error occurs. How can I achieve this?

I call it from another module as follows-

```
log.s3 = await pushToS3(bucketName, filename, data)
```

...where log is an object and s3 is its property (also an object)

When I pass the correct parameters, the data gets pushed to s3 and the promise gets resolved and I get the following in log.s3-

> "s3": {
>           "success": true,
>           "message": {
>               "ETag": "someETag",
>               "VersionId": "someVersionId"
>           }
>       }

but when I enter wrong parameters, say a `bucketName` that doesn't exist, I get an error, which I add to the `s3Info` object in the `pushToS3` function. I just can't get that object back to the calling function.

This is what I expect when an error occurs-

> { success: false,   message:    { AccessDenied: Access Denied
>          at Request.extractError (F:\workspace\webScraping\botsWorkingOnKeywords\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\services\s3.js:585:35)
>          at Request.callListeners (F:\workspace\webScraping\botsWorkingOnKeywords\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\sequential_executor.js:106:20)
>          at Request.emit (F:\workspace\webScraping\botsWorkingOnKeywords\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\sequential_executor.js:78:10)
>          at Request.emit (F:\workspace\webScraping\botsWorkingOnKeywords\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:683:14)
>          at Request.transition (F:\workspace\webScraping\botsWorkingOnKeywords\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:22:10)
>          at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (F:\workspace\webScraping\botsWorkingOnKeywords\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\state_machine.js:14:12)
>          at F:\workspace\webScraping\botsWorkingOnKeywords\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\state_machine.js:26:10
>          at Request. (F:\workspace\webScraping\botsWorkingOnKeywords\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:38:9)
>          at Request. (F:\workspace\webScraping\botsWorkingOnKeywords\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:685:12)
>          at Request.callListeners (F:\workspace\webScraping\botsWorkingOnKeywords\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\sequential_executor.js:116:18)
>        message: 'Access Denied',
>        code: 'AccessDenied',
>        region: null,
>        time: 2019-04-16T04:07:30.545Z,
>        requestId: 12345,
>        extendedRequestId:
>         'NhyakPOYrMZ4RoRrwaqFSXZFx2c2lrb4+x+HzN/oQiL+7+AyG9RnyXA3CLbJfdOj0GZiIUJSB3U=',
>        cfId: undefined,
>        statusCode: 403,
>        retryable: false,
>        retryDelay: 74.88976302089922 } }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the code where you are calling your function, you would wrap the function call in a try/catch statement. When you call `reject()` in your function, it will throw an error. You can catch that error and get the data you passed to `reject()` from the error object, transform it and return whatever is appropriate

```
async function main() {
  try {
    // ... do your things
    log.s3 = await pushToS3(bucketName, filename, data)
    return someValue;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return error;
  }
}
```

Comment: I just kept the `return new Promise` statement inside the try block and it worked.

`try{
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
         s3.putObject(params, (err, data) => {`

instead of

`return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      s3.putObject(params, (err, data) => {`

And thanks for telling me that when we reject, the passed value is caught by the catch block in the calling function. Appreciate it.